# How to evict instance immediately from local registry cache(client side) when remote service is down?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

When a service deregisters itself, Eureka server can sense it immediately, but the clients cannot due to the multi level caches(eureka client cache, ribbon cache).

Can I manually remove the deregistered instance instead of waiting for cache update? This is important because some requests will fail due to the latency of the offline instance removal.

Comment: Here is the answer which may help you-
[Speeding up Netflix-Eureka Unregistration not working for Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344193/speeding-up-netflix-eureka-unregistration-not-working-for-spring-boot/51363218#51363218)

Comment: @Sachin Thanks. But... I've already known this method. It can not eliminate the latency, only decrease it. What I really need is an approach to remove target instance programmatically instead of waiting for cache

Comment: That's true, but as for as I know even Eureka can not sense it immediately.  Server always waits for heart beat signal. As for as I remember default configuration is 90 seconds before Eureka server expires the client instance. Client sends lease renewal heart beat signal every 30 seconds (default configuration).   So, it will wait for 90 seconds before it removes the instance then comes client side caching. I think in your case first you will have to reduce this timing and then find a way to query eureka server directly and clear your client cache. :)